# Trying to print out the contents of an ArrayList

Tags: java

I'm trying to print out the contents of the ArrayList "list", but I keep getting what I think is the locations of the elements and not the contents.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Assignment23 {

public static void main (String[] args){

ArrayList<Point> list = new ArrayList<Point>();
for(int i = 0; i < 99; i++){
    list.add(new Point());
}
Collections.sort(list);
System.out.println(""+list);
}
}
class Point implements Comparable<Point>{
int x = (int)(Math.random()*-10);
int y = (int)(Math.random()*-10);
```

Comment: Just use a `foreach` loop to iterate over the list.

Comment: By _locations_ I think you mean _location in memory_ (i.e. the object's base address). That's a bit ambiguous because you're talking about _points_ here, which also describe locations!

Comment: Heehee, yeah sorry, I meant address :3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To print out the contents of the `ArrayList`, use a `for loop`:

```
for (Point p : list)
    System.out.println("point x: " + p.x ", point y: " + p.y);
```

Comment: Awesome! Compact and does the job!

Answer (score 6):

You will find you get much better results for this and in many situations if you implement `toString` for `Point` and most classes that you write. Consider this:

```
@Override public String toString()
{
     return String.format("(%d,%d)", x, y);
}
```

Comment: +1 for using `String.format` instead of a series of string concatenations. I think the Java compiler is smart enough to do something efficient with the concatenations, but the format string version is always more readable. (Assuming of course that the reader knows how to read format strings!)

Answer (score 3):

Over write toString method in point

```
class Point implements Comparable<Point>{
  int x = (int)(Math.random()*-10);
  int y = (int)(Math.random()*-10);

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
   return "["+x+","+y+"]";
  }
}
```

Usage is same :

```
Collections.sort(list);
System.out.println("Points["+list+"]);
```

You will get output like

```
Points[[20,10],[15,10]...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Override `toString()` method on  Point class.

```
class Point implements Comparable<Point>{

    @Override
    public String toString() {
         return "x =" + x  + ", y="+y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
System.out.println(""+list.get(i).x);  //Or whatever element in `Point` you want to print
```

The reason you were getting an unexpected result is that your list consists of `Point` objects. So calling `list.get(i)` returns an entire `Point`, whereas you want to specify that field in the `Point` to print out.